# Stacked histogram by decade from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that contains the date of a snowstorm and also a ranking of said snowstorm ranging from 1950-2019. I want to create a stacked histogram where the x-axis is decade and the y-axis is counts of snowstorm by category.

An example of what I am trying to create is listed below. [image: Snowstorm climatology]

I am having trouble understanding how exactly to aggregate the data in such a fashion that would allow me to plot something like I shared.

For example, here is a snippet of the 1950s dataframe:

```
    Start       End         Category    Year    count
    1959-03-12  1959-03-14  2           1950    13
    1958-03-18  1958-03-23  3           1950    6
    1958-02-12  1958-02-18  3           1950    6
    1957-12-03  1957-12-05  1           1950    32
    1956-03-18  1956-03-20  1           1950    32
```

I have all of the counts for each category, but how do I turn that into data that is plottable on stacked histogram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate you data first, then plot with the argument `stacked=True`

#### `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table('count', 'Year', 'Category', 'sum').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

#### `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Category'])['count'].sum().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Keep in mind that you can change the aggregation to something else.

```
df.pivot_table('count', 'Year', 'Category', 'first').plot.bar(stacked=True)
df.groupby(['Year', 'Category'])['count'].first().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Also, you can drop duplicates prior.

```
(
    df.drop_duplicates(['Year', 'Category'])
      .pivot_table('count', 'Year', 'Category')
      .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Comment: Hi this is exactly what I am looking for. However, when using the sum command it sums every value in the 'count' column. So from my original example, it goes 13+6+6+32+32. I want it to essentially count each one as one instance. The 'count' column already sums up each one, but just puts the total sum next to each event. How would I go about changing that?

Comment: You have multiple rows with the same year and category.  You mean to say that the count of 6 for category 3 is simply repeated?  If so, replace `sum` with `first`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I plot more than one on the same graph? When I try and do a different decade it simply creates a new plot.

Comment: You should put all decades in the same dataframe.  I'm assuming `'Year'` will define the decade.